# Javascript and mongo db , how to pass arrays of conditions to a query

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, nodes

Pass an array of conditions. Make a request where the conditions are arrays
Data will be updated based on the filters.

## array of filters

```
bodystyle = ["body style 1" , "body style 2"]
model   = [" model " , " model 2" ]
make = ["make 1" , "make2"]
year = ["2015 , 2019]
```

## Query

```
 keystone.list('Vehicle').model.update({ bodystyle: bodystyle , model: model, make: make, year : year}, { ....
```

Comment: Did you try using [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) as `keystone.list('Vehicle').model.update({ bodystyle: { $in: bodystyle }, model: { $in: model }, make: { $in: make }, year : { $in: year } }, { ....`

Comment: i have tried this solution but it do works using 1 condition   keystone.list('Vehicle').model.update({ bodystyle: { $in: this.bodystyle } } but when i use all conditions nothing was modified it did not update the data

Comment: multiple $In does not work @chridam

Comment: Well that depends on the exclusivity of the queries, are they mutually exclusive? The above assumes they aren't since they are used with an implicit `$and`. If they are mutually exclusive then wrap them within an `$or` operator i.e. `keystone.list('Vehicle').model.update({ $or: [ { bodystyle: { $in: bodystyle } }, { model: { $in: model } }, { make: { $in: make } }, { year : { $in: year } } ] }, { ....`

Comment: what does mutually exclusive means Sir ?

Comment: post an answer sir so i can mark it for your points. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above assumes your queries are not mutually exclusive (i.e. to return any results they all have to match) since they are used with an implicit `$and`.

If they are mutually exclusive (i.e. if one query does not match the others can still return results) then wrap the them within an `$or` operator i.e.

```
keystone.list('Vehicle').model.update({ 
    $or: [ 
        { bodystyle: { $in: bodystyle } }, 
        { model: { $in: model } }, 
        { make: { $in: make } }, 
        { year : { $in: year } } 
    ] 
}, { .... }, callback)
```

Comment: I see, but what if I wanted to make year = ["2015 , 2019] as an $or and the rest as an $and ?

Answer (score 0):

I expect you want to apply 'OR' conditions to each array of filters. 
If so, you have to threat them in js, before passing them as params, to construct the query part of your request with '$or' conditions encapsulated in a '$and' condition, as follow :

```
{
  $and: [
    {
      $or: [
          {bodystyle : "body style 1"},
          {bodystyle : "body style 2"},
          ]
    },
   {
      $or: [
          {model : "model "},
          {model : "model 2"},
          ]
    },
    {
      $or: [
          {model : "model "},
          {model : "model 2"},
          ]
    },
    {
      $or: [
          {make : "make 1"},
          {make : "make2"},
          ]
    },
     {
      $or: [
          {year : 2015},
          {year : 2019},
          ]
    },
  ]
}
```

EDIT : As proposed in @chridam comment, $in operator can do the job in a simplier way

Comment: what if the data came from an api whom i cannot changes the data structure ?